# Как сохранить ссылки

Tags: java, android

Задача в следующем:
Пользователь вставляет ссылку в диалог(может добавлять несколько ссылок), после чего нажимает ок(на данный момент в приложении ссылки служат для получения preview видео).

Пример кода:

```
    void getIdUrl(String url, int position) {
    String video_id = "";
    String expression = "";
    if (url != null && url.trim().length() > 0 && url.matches(".*\\byoutube\\b.*")) {
        expression = "^.*((youtu.be" + "\\/)" + "|(v\\/)|(\\/u\\/w\\/)|(embed\\/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#\\&\\?]*).*";
        CharSequence input = url;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String groupIndex1 = matcher.group(7);
            if (groupIndex1 != null && groupIndex1.length() == 11)
                video_id = groupIndex1;
            ImageUpload imageUpload = new ImageUpload();
            imageUpload.setLoadImage(true);
            OutputMetadata outputMetadata = new OutputMetadata();
            outputMetadata.setVideoUrl("http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id + "/0.jpg");
            outputMetadata.setFilename("http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id + "/0.jpg");
            imageUpload.setOutputMetadata(outputMetadata);
            controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().add(0, imageUpload);
            adapterForm.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Необходимо сохранит ссылку/ссылки, которые **вводит пользователь в диалоге** и потом использовать(без всяких там БД).

Comment: всего одну ссылку? ***"Потом использовать"*** Что вы тут имели ввиду? Каждый раз использовать, или в течении работы программ?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT мне нужно сохранять ссылки, чтоб потом мог открывать корректные видео(по ссылкам), которые ввёл пользователь.

Comment: @Inkognito а почему Вы не хотите использовать БД? На мой взгляд это наиболее подходящий вариант хранения множества ссылок и их многократного использования

Comment: @НикитаЛещёв я не собираюсь их использовать многократно. Пользователь переходит во фрагмент, вставляет ссылки в диалог, формируется список preview видео из этих ссылок. Мне нужно их сохранять для того, чтобы в будущем осуществить по их нажатию открытие корректных видео.

Answer (score 1):

Если создание БД для хранения всего лишь ссылок это овер-ворк, то есть вариант `SharedPreferences` это подходит для локального хранения любой `Serializable` информации.

Создаете класс:

```
public class UserPreferences {
private static final String URLS_SET = "urls_set";
@Nonnull
private final SharedPreferences preferences;
@Nonnull
private final Gson gson;

public void addUrl(String url) {
    final String json = preferences.getString(URLS_SET, null);

    final Type type = new TypeToken<Set<String>>() {
    }.getType();

    final Set<String> set;
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(json)) {
        set = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    } else {
        set = new HashSet<String>();
    }
    set.add(url);

    final String newJson = gson.toJson(set);
    preferences.edit().putString(URLS_SET, newJson).commit();
}

private List<String> getUrl() {
    final String json = preferences.getString(URLS_SET, null);

    final Type type = new TypeToken<Set<String>>() {
    }.getType();

    final List<String> list = Lists.<String>newArrayList();
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(json)) {
        list.addAll(gson.<Set<String>>fromJson(json, type));
    }

    return list;
}

}
```

Само-собою это синглтон, так что нужно добавить конструктор (я юзаю Даггер2, так что не стал его сюда добавлять)

Ну и после этого можно в любом месте приложения достать актуальный список урлов.